# Inverse of a piecewise function with even/odd condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inverse-function

Given a function $f:\mathbb{N_0}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z^+}$
and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $b > a$

$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
c+b\times\frac{n}{2}, & \text{if }n \text{ is even}\\
c+a+b\times\frac{n-1}{2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\
\end{cases}$$

How to calculate the inverse of this function?

Comment: The function need not be one-to-one. For example, if $a=b=c=1$, then $f(3)=f(4)$.

Comment: @quasi Yes, you are right. I edited the question.

Comment: Hint: 
$$
f^{-1}(m)
=
\begin{cases}
??&&\text{if}\;m\equiv c\;(\text{mod}\;b)\\
??&&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: @quasi Thanks for the hint. I solved the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f^{-1}(m) = \begin{cases} 2\times \frac{m-c}{b}&&\text{if}\;m\equiv c\;(\text{mod}\;b)\\ 1+2\times \frac{m-c-a}{b}&&\text{otherwise}\\ \end{cases}$$

Comment: Some care is needed:$\;f^{-1}$ is only defined on the range of $f$, which can be expressed as
$$
\Bigl\{
m\in\mathbb{Z}^+
{\,{\Large{\mid}}\,}
\bigl(m\ge c\bigr)
\;\,\text{and}\;\,
\Bigl(
\bigl(m\equiv c\;(\text{mod}\;b)\bigr)
\;\,\text{or}\;\,
\bigl(m\equiv c+a\;(\text{mod}\;b)\bigr)
\Bigr)
\Bigr\}
$$
With that restriction, your answer is correct.